# Android App activities installed as multiple icons

Tags: android

My Android App has 2 activities. A login screen and a search screen. When I deploy the app on emulator or on my device, I see 2 icons for same app. When I click on icon 1 it opens screen 1 (login screen) and When I click on icon 2 it opens screen 2 (search screen). By logic when I login it should show the search screen. Not sure when I'm making the mistake.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Your manifest file should only have this line in the activity you want to have an icon:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN" />
```

Based on your description, it sounds like both activities have this line.

Comment: `MAIN` is not a category; it is an action. More generally, do not include an `<intent-filter>` for an activity in the manifest unless you need one. For simple apps, only the activity that needs an icon in the launcher should have an `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: Hi Aaron,

Thank you so much for the quick revert. Yes this was the issue and the app works as intended. Thanks again.

Regards,
Aravind. C

Comment: You should check also the manifest for referenced library projects

Comment: Thanks for the little detail.

Answer (score 27):

In your mainfest file when you have following tag in two different activities tags at the time, Android app seems to be installed twice.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I've got same problem because I included a library as project dependency, whose AndroidManifest.xml contained an intent filter definition -> I removed it and everything started working correctly!

Comment: Actually, I have this in two different activities, because I want each to behave as an independent app. It works as desired. I tried with "CREATE_SHORTCUT", but the shortcut does not stays in the home screen.

Answer (score 5):

The comment made by @Adrian C on his answer solved our problem.

The manifest file of our main application had only one `intent-filter` tag specifying only one activity as the launcher activity for the application.

So I had to look deeper...

We included library projects (luckily written by us) and the manifest file of one of the library projects had an `intent-filter` tag on its activity specifying that activity as the launcher activity.

When we then included that library project in our main application (which has its own `intent-filter` specifying a launcher activity), the complete source code saw two `intent-filter` tags specifying two activities as launcher activities and therefore two application icons were created.

When we removed the `intent-filter` specifying a launcher activity in the library project, the second app launcher icon disappeared.