# double icon android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, android-manifest

I created application, but when I run it in emulator it appeared with double icon which some time have different function(one of them is the last edit).

How to make it just one icon?

Comment: i think you should define the icone on the manifest file, and that's enough

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android App activities installed as multiple icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527263/android-app-activities-installed-as-multiple-icons)

Answer (score 0):

**Check that only one of your `Activity` defined into the `AndroidManifest.xml` should have the`intent-filter` defined with `action.MAIN` and`category.LAUNCHER`**:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

if you have several activities with this configurations you will have several launcher icons.