# How to install only starting activity

Tags: android

I develope an android app, it works great, but when I install that app, all the activities that are in the app also get install separatelly.

Can anybody tell me how fix it so that only main starting activity get install??????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android App actvities installed as multiple icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527263/android-app-actvities-installed-as-multiple-icons)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but as @bangrang says, post your manifest. I suspect you're declaring all of your activities with category LAUNCHER.

Answer (score 3):

```
Check your manifest your main activity that you want to launch should be like the code below


 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>


and all other class should be declared as below


 <activity android:name=".Google"/>
    <activity android:name=".ExampleClass"/>
```