# Multiple apps on my emulator for my one project

Tags: android-studio

Wondering why I'm working on one project in my Android Studio window, but when using the emulator, I see multiple applications that go to different activities. I'm trying to develop one application, not a couple that toss the user around to different applications.

[image: Here's a screencap]

I also notice that when I uninstall one application from virtual machine/emulator, all four icons disappear.

EDIT: Found an answer on a different thread: [Android App activities installed as multiple icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527263/android-app-activities-installed-as-multiple-icons)

Comment: Found a related thread that answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527263/android-app-activities-installed-as-multiple-icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your manifest:

prpbably you have more than one activity with intent filter tag

```
<intent-filter>
    <action
        android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

once delete all from emulator and in your project manifest just luncher activity must have intent-filter tag

Comment: Yup, all of the activities in my manifest had the

```<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>```

line, which I guess creates an icon for every activity that line is in. I removed that line from all activities except for the one I wanted the app to start at. Looks like it worked.