# Why do two icons appear after .apk installation?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

My main activity has a button that opens the Libgdx game, which was what I wanted, but when I test the app on my phone or on the emulator, two application icons appear. One of them opens the game directly, the other one is the main app that contains the button that starts the game class.

Is there a way to hide one of them? Or what is the proper thing to do? I could not find any information on the internet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: [Android App activities installed as multiple icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527263/android-app-activities-installed-as-multiple-icons/7644364)

I had an extra

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN" />
```